# FP language: removing empty lists from a list

Tags: functional-programming

Suppose I've got the sequence `<1,<>,2,<>>`.

How could I go about deleting the empty lists and get `<1,2>`?
Ideally, without using recursion or iteration.

Thanks.

PS: I'm using [FP programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: `without using recursion or iteration` - this only leaves magic... and flatMap. which is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is [`filter`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Filter). It takes a predicate and takes out elements not satisfying it.

Since the FP language has a weird syntax and I couldn't find any documentation , I can't provide an implementation of `filter`. But in general, it can be implemented using a [`fold`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) -- which is just the `insert`s from the link you provided.

Here's what I mean (in Haskell):

```
filter p list = foldr (\x xs -> if p x then x:xs else xs) [] list¹
```

If you don't get this, look [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Filter). When you have written `filter`, you can call it like

```
newList = filter notEmpty theList
```

(where `nonEmpty` is a predicate or lambda). Oh, and of course this only hides recursion by using another function; at some point, you *have* to recurse.

¹The : operator in Haskell is list consing (appending an element to the head), not function application.